# MongoDB throwing exception on resolving connection string (C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb, dns

---

I'm building a winform app that initially connects to a MongoDB server using Driver 2.10.
When I try and connect on my own machine everything works smooth, but when trying to install
clients on other computers via a msi file, the app crashes and I get the following:

```
ERROR - List of configured name servers must not be empty.
Parameter name: servers
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.QueryInternal(DnsQuestion question, DnsQuerySettings queryOptions, IReadOnlyCollection`1 servers)
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.Query(DnsQuestion question)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString.Resolve(Boolean resolveHosts)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl.Resolve(Boolean resolveHosts)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(MongoUrl url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)
   at PaladinFormV2.MongoCRUD..ctor(String i_database)
   at PaladinFormV2.Paladin..ctor(Boolean onboarding)
   at PaladinFormV2.Program.Main()
```

I'm connecting through a connection string as follows:

`MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://[name]:[pass]@mcsamples-nwups.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");`

What am I doing wrong and what information am I missing here to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after a long time trying to figure out what went wrong here, I came to the conclusion that using the '+srv' inside the connection string tries to resolve the DNS server on which your mongo instance is running, for clients using this it may cause the app to crash.

My fix was using a different connection string that does not use this prefix.
The info on connection string was taken from here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score -1):

Edit your connection string
From

```
`MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://[name]:[pass]@mcsamples-nwups.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")`
```

To

```
`MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://[name]:[pass]@mcsamples-nwups.mongodb.net/test")`
```

**Also make sure you have internet connection to the cloud server**